# how do I video-record a narrated powerpoint-like pdf presentation?

Tags: 18.04, desktop-recording

The title is pretty self-explanatory:  I have a pdf version of a powerpoint-like presentation (created with latex and beamer, not that it matters).  I would like to record a video presentation of me narrating over it.

I used to do this with camtasia in windows, but for some reason camtasia no longer works for me.  So I've turned to linux : )

I've already tried various linux desktop recording, AKA screencasting, programs, including kazam, gtk-recordmydesktop, obs-studio, simplescreenrecorder, and vokoscreen, among others.  Frustratingly, I can't get any of these to work the way I need.

Actually, I don't need much.  I just want to be able to record (from my microphone) while I talk and scroll through the pdf slides.  Surely this is possible, somehow.

But how?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

EDIT:  I forgot to add, I'm using the latest lubuntu, version 18.04.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I use vokoscreen and it does exactly what you asked for, recording voice and video of beamer presentation. You only need to configure it to record fullscreen and then choose the audio device (microphone).

Comment: Okay, I'll try vokoscreen again I guess. If I recall correctly, last time I tried it I was able to record the video but unable to get it to record audio from my mic. But like I said, I'll try again in a little while. Thanks for the info.

Comment: You're welcome, For audio i used Pulse and I chose the built-in microphone.

Comment: Okay, so I re-installed vokoscreen and selected "pulse" for audio. However I only get options for "built-in audio analog stereo" and "monitor of built-in audio analog stereo". I don't see any options for a mic.

Comment: Oh and not only that, even when I try to record video, when I stop recording it gives me the error: "usr/bin/ffmpeg is crashed". So, it seems unlikely I'll be able to get vokoscreen to work for me. Maybe it's because I'm using an old laptop, and not modern hardware.

Comment: The built-in audio analog stereo is the built-in mic. After the crash of ffmpeg no file is generated?

Comment: I just made a test using obs-studio and I had pretty much the same results, it could be a way out